# is it possible to store mongodb data on hdfs

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, data-storage

In my project, I'm challenging with data storage method. Firstly, in my project, there are streaming data in JSON format and most suitable db is MongoDB. I have to analyze data with Hadoop or Spark.

So, my conflict starts here: Can I store MongoDB collections in HDFS or must MongoDB and HDFS storage units be different? It is an important issue for my decision. Must I use Hadoop and MongoDB in same disk units or separate units?

Comment: [Hadoop and MongoDB Integration Overview](https://www.mongodb.com/hadoop-and-mongodb), [Using MongoDB with Hadoop & Spark: Part 1](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/using-mongodb-hadoop-spark-part-1-introduction-setup), [Using MongoDB with Hadoop & Spark: Part 2](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/using-mongodb-hadoop-spark-part-2-hive-example), [Using MongoDB with Hadoop & Spark: Part 3](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/using-mongodb-hadoop-spark-part-3-spark-example-key-takeaways).

Comment: @zero323, i read that tutorials before but my question isn'a about using hadoop and mongodb together. i asked that when I use both of them do i need two seperate cluster for each other or can i use both of them in one cluster?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/hadoop/

Answer (score 0):

They need to be different units since the methods of storage, security policy implementations and storage mechanisms themselves are different.